# Language switcher does not display the correct link to the default language path

Tags: i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I maintain a bilingual English/French website and the `Language Switcher` block is available on every page to allow the user to switch language. It works except on one particular taxonomy term page and all it's descendants:

When the language is set to English (default), the `Language Switcher` displays the correct links. English links to the EN page and French links to the FR page.

But when the language is set to French (i.e the user has clicked on French), both English and French options link to the french page (with `/fr/rest-of-the-path/`).

Any idea where the cause of this behaviour lies in?

Comment: I have the same problem on *all* pages, not just on a particular taxonomy term page. I am using language paths of the form "example.com" for the English site and "fr.example.com" for the French site. Drupal tells me that the language path for the default language may be left blank, so that's what I did. However, when I *do* set the language path "en.example.com" for the default language then the language switcher properly switches back to English after having switched to French first. I would prefer to *not* have an additional path for the default language though. Is this a bug in core?

Comment: It turned out to be related to the Menu Token module. I fixed it by disabling it

Comment: I've never had the module installed. Unfortunately, I still don't know what's causing the problem.

Comment: Also see https://drupal.org/node/2053653

Comment: What Multilanguage Options has you Vocabulary? Is it set to Localize or Translation?

Comment: I have a multilangual site and all works fine. I had notice the same problem when I wrote a module which helps me to customize the language switcher links, but I fixed that, the problem was there. Are you using any code/module which might have any influence on the language switcher links?

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because the term itself have no multilanguage path. From my experience the only way to have mulitlanguage path to a term is to create them by hand with an URL-Alias or by installing the `[Pathauto i18n Taxonomy][1]` Module. This helped me a lot

Comment: Please see my comment. This is not taxonomy page specific for me.